# Writing a streamer for raspberry pi

Tags: video, raspberry-pi

I want to write a simple video playback software for Raspberry Pi that plays videos from a given path or URL.

I thought of slaving MPlayer or using VLCLib (both with Python), but I've read that VLC doesn't show video on RaspberryPi and that MPlayer's playback is unbearably slow.

I though of using MonoGame (XNA) and C#, but that seems like a bit of a stretch.

What are my options for playing High-Definition Video on a PI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Gstreamer?

I can't say I wholeheartedly recommend it as I'm currently battling with it for a similar project, but it does seem to be a very popular / widely supported system with great flexibility and modularity.

Downside - the documentation is on a par with most *nix documentation.